# Get instagram posts with a certain text in their captions

Tags: python, automation, instagram, caption

So, I would like some help on how I could do something.
I would like to **get instagram posts links that contains a certain text in their caption**.
I also would like to **get the posts posted within a certaing period of time**.
Do you guys know how to do it? Do you have any recomendations on where I could learn how to do it (websites, YouTube channels...)?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: so basically `if text in caption: print(text)` or sth like that?

Comment: Also You have to provide Your efforts and what have You tried regarding this issue. Show Your code. Provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)